# Password protected website

Tags: security, authentication, password, homepage, http-code-503

I need to add a user authentication page before the actual homepage of the website.

In Joomla! I just set the website offline and the offline page loads in place of the homepage but then it's automatically throwing a "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" error which I would like to avoid.
That's why I would like to know the other ways to load an authentication page before the homepage.

NB: I'm using Apache servers if that's relevant
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution on the Apache server side is using [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

See the section ["Getting it working"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) for an example. And here some answers on [Stackoverflow](https://serverfault.com/questions/127708/how-to-configure-basic-authentication-in-apache-httpd-virtual-hosts).

Pro: If you have access to the command line and your webserver it's a 2 minute set up that blocks access to your project.

Con: Managing access this way for many users might be inconvenient. And you need access to the command line and your webserver :-)

Comment: Is there any possibility to manage it from the control panel given by the hosting server ?

Comment: Well, I don't know your control panel but the ones I know all support basic HTTP password protection. Your provider/support surely will know.